# Prolog - Reading through a list

Tags: list, prolog

For a problem in my class, I'm having trouble figuring out how to read through a list of numbers in Prolog. The idea is that a predicate called *contains_big* would read through a list of given numbers, and respond with "true" if a number in that list is over 100, and false if not.

```
contains_big([40, 692, 2, 800, 7]). = true
contains_big([2, 4, 6]).            = false
```

How would this be accomplished in prolog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an earlier exercise we have predicate `classify/2`

```
% classify(+N, ?Classification)

classify(N, small)   :- must_be(number,N), N < 50, !.
classify(N, medium)  :- must_be(number,N), N >= 50, N =< 100, !.
classify(N, big)     :- must_be(number,N), N > 100.
```

Now you just have to apply that predicate to every element in the list, in effect performing a disjunction of the query `classify(N,big)` for every `N` in that list.

Here is a simple way: We code the inductive definition...

- A nonempty list `[N|_]` starting with `N` contains a big element if `N` is big (and the we do not need to look at the rest of the list, and the Prolog to not try the next clause by adding a `!`).
- A nonempty list `[_|More]` starting with anything and continuing with `More` (which may or may not be the empty list) contains a big element if `More` is a list containing a big element.

```
contains_big([N|_])    :- classify(N, big),!.  
contains_big([_|More]) :- contains_big(More).
```

And that's it, really.

And so:

```
?- contains_big([]).
false.

?- contains_big([1,2,3]).
false.

?- contains_big([1,200,3]).
true.

?- contains_big([200,200,200]).
true.
```